# Connect erlang nodes on docker

Tags: docker, erlang, elixir

I have two docker images containing a released elixir app.
I run these two dockers on my local machine.
And I'm trying to connect the two nodes.
How can i run the released app on a named node?
or - is there any other way to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you would do it without `docker-compose` for Erlang nodes.

### 1. Create the network

```
docker network create example
```

### 2. Start docker containers

#### Terminal 1

```
$ docker run --rm -it --name bar -h bar --net example erlang:19.3 /bin/bash
root@bar:/# erl -sname bar -setcookie example
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3.5.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.3.5.1  (abort with ^G)
(bar@bar)1>
```

#### Terminal 2

```
docker run --rm -it --name foo -h foo --net example erlang:19.3 /bin/bash
root@foo:/# erl -sname foo -setcookie example
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3.5.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.3.5.1  (abort with ^G)
(foo@foo)1>
```

### 3. Check connectivity

#### Terminal 1

```
(foo@foo)1> net_adm:ping(bar@bar).
pong
```

#### Terminal 2

```
(bar@bar)1> net_adm:ping(foo@foo).
pong
```

## Getting a remote shell for a release running on a docker container

### 1. Start a `bash` shell in one of the two docker containers

```
docker exec -it foo /bin/bash
```

Where `foo` is the name for the docker container.

### 2. Start a remote shell

`./rel/your_app/bin/your_app console`

I assume you know the path to the release inside the container.

Comment: hmm. my app is released in the image . don't have erlang/elixir on it .

Comment: The principle is the same though. The release contains the Erlang RunTime System (ERTS) which starts an Erlang node. If you set up the `docker network` and provide a host (`-h`) for the running docker containers, the two Erlang nodes should be able to connect to each other.

Comment: ok, so how can run an erlang/elixir command (to connect the nodes) without having an interactive shell ?

Comment: Based on this comment "so i can [...] call a genserver that is on a different node" I assumed you already knew how to access an interactive shell for your release running on the docker container.
I will update the answer with instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

Something like this:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  elixir1:
    image: image-name
    #(other configs here, like ports, volumes)

  elixir2:
    image: image-name
    #(other configs here, like ports, volumes)
```

Then, you are able to point DNS `elixir1` and `elixir2` with that names among them.

Replace your `docker run` commands with:

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: When I run the images with docker-compose, are they connected ?

Comment: Yes, docker-compose by default put containers in the same docker-network. Each container has its own private IP, and a DNS is set-up in order to translate the service-name to the corresponding IP.

Comment: having it on the same network is not enough for me , i want them to be connected, so i can , for example, call a genserver that is on a different node. something like : `Node.connect` in elixir

Comment: @fay Did you ever find a solution to clustering within docker compose. I have a solution on docker-cloud using docker swarm but not been able to solve it for local development in docker-compose